# How to read the data with button press in SwiftUI view where, data called from function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, alamofire

I am trying to learn network request using Alamofire in SwiftUI. I am trying to fetch data from a URL and display it on my simulator screen. I have used a button on tap of which , the fetched data will get displayed. The problem is on tap of the button nothing is getting printed.

I tried using debugPrint() and print() turn by turn, but nothing is getting printed , neither on simulator screen nor in console. How do i achieve the same, here is what i tried -->

```
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var tapped : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Button(action: read, label: {
                Text("Let's Begin!")
            })
            .padding()
        }
        
    }
}

func read() {
    print ("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")
    AF.request("https://httpbin.org/get").response { response in
            debugPrint("Response : \(response)")
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Hint: `ObservableObject`

Comment: Your code works well for me. On MacOS 14.4, using Xcode 15.3, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst. I get `"Response : success(Optional(444 bytes))"` . In Xcode Signing & Capabilities -> App Sandbox, make sure you tick the `outgoing connections client`

Comment: In the simplest case, you don't even need `ObservableObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would bounce it over to a task, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isReading : Bool = false
    @State var result = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Button(action: {
                isReading.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text(isReading ? "Cancel" : "Let's Begin!")
            })
            .padding()
            .task(id: isReading) {
                if !isReading { return }
                do {
                    result = await read()
                }
                catch {
                    // use error
                }
                isReading = false
            }
        }
    }
}

func read() async throws -> String {
    print ("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")

    let response = try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            AF.request("https://httpbin.org/get")
            .responseData { response in
                switch(response.result) {
                case let .success(data):
                    continuation.resume(returning: data)
                case let .failure(error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
            }
        }
    let result = // process response into your result
    return result
}
```